# put a web service client in axis2 inside a maven webapp in tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, rampart

I need to consume a secure webservice from inside my webservice deployed in axis2-tomcat.

my problem is with the resources I need to consume the secure webservice. for example in a class that act as a client for this secure web service i can do this:

```
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "keys\\store.jks");
```

Or

```
          sc.engageModule("rampart");
```

But if I put this class inside my webservice how i can find this resources that I have inside my webservice of course.

Any tips.

Answer (score 3):

To read resources(property files or `trustStore` file or else) from the `servlet` you may use:
`getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` 
Like:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

InputStream is =
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("someResource.properties");

props.load(is);
```

BTW
 To call a secured webservice you may see [Apache CXF Conduit](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html), that will serve the easy way.
At lest if you dont want to use CXF, The part `Configuring SSL Support` will give you ideas.

Comment: and in the case that the web service client need to be put inside another webservice, haw I can access this resources??

Comment: The web service client code can be a separate class, in the constructor you may have the code. If using Spring, the injection will work.

Comment: we don´t use spring in this scenario. the problem we have is for example that we need to specified the path of the keystore in this way:         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "keys\\store.jks"); and the client class not found the resource, so we need to know how to tell the right path inside the webservice.

Comment: Can't you have a .properties file in resources, having a key like trustStore="keys\store.jks", then reading the .properties file they way mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Inside the webservice that contain the client classes I create a folder keys and inside this folder I put store.jks. Actually maven do this for me :-D . So I need to know the real path to this folder and file, because keys\store.jks not work inside the webservice